# How do I find a flute teacher?

Tags: learning, flute

I would like to learn to play the flute, but it is nearly impossible to find a flute teacher around here. I have tried the music store and they don't teach the flute there nor do they know of someone who does. I looked online through a large number of directories designed to help people find a teacher and I seem to be out of luck.

I know for a fact that there are people around here that teach various instruments. However, no-one seems to be listing their skill in the paper or on Craigslist. What can I do to find a flute teacher? Should I list that I need a flute teacher in the paper or something?

My last flute teacher was located right outside Chicago, over 60 miles away, which turned out to be too far for me. I live in SW Michigan, but going to NW Indiana wouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Musicians in a limited geographic area usually know one another.

If you know any, then ask them about any music schools in the area, about where they studied, about their teachers, etc. Even if none of them play the flute they might know someone that does and might be able to help you.

If you don't know any other musicians in the area then go meet some! Find out where local musicians perform (is probably advertised or promoted somewhere). There are always local bands, singers, etc. Approach them when you can, introduce yourself, express your interest and ask away!

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried contacting the local high school band teacher? Nearly every high school in America has a band program, and those band programs have flute players. Music teachers usually (should) have a list of private instructors they will refer excellent students to for private and summer instruction.

They'll likely be more or less local, too, since busy high school students can't always travel an hour to go to a weekly lesson.

Also, shot in the dark: http://betterfly.com/7245093636 -- Edwardsburg, MI?

Go to http://betterfly.com/category/flute/ and type in your zip code, you may find someone that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you know anyone else who plays flute, you should ask them if they know of local teachers.  There might also be teachers who do both flute and other woodwinds, so possibly expand the pool of people you ask to clarinet players and the like.