# What are some good ways to find and choose a Bansuri Guru (teacher)

Tags: bansuri, teachers

What are some good ways to find and choose a Bansuri Guru teacher

Google turns up so many results, how do I know which is the right one? And they cost a fortune!

Comment: This question might be closed since questions requesting websites or apps are off-topic, but a question about "What are some good ways to find and choose a teacher" could be useful, and I don't see an obvious duplicate of it. Please edit to clarify: Do you mean that you're looking for online (video-conferencing) lessons, or using online tools to find an in-person teacher? (If you mean the second, the answer is that there are better ways.) Unfortunately, most good teachers do cost a lot; you're paying an artisan with a niche skill for their time. Also unfortunately, many bad teachers do too.

Comment: @PiedPiper (Now why didn't that show up for me when searching for "how to find a teacher"? Honestly.) But it seems like that one is entirely about how to assess and choose between teachers, not how to go about even locating candidates. [Here's one that focuses more on that.](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/100/how-do-i-find-a-flute-teacher)

Comment: @AndyBonner The poster has a list of candidates from Google.

Comment: @PiedPiper True, though my advice would be "throw them away and start with word-of-mouth." Unless, Marium, you're actually looking for an "online teacher," in which case I'd still want to talk to colleagues or students of potential teachers.